# Why is the electric flux of a point charge inside a sphere not 0 since its a vector and all the field lines point outward?

Tags: electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

I know that the magnitude of the total flux of a point charge is $\frac{q}{ϵ_0}$, and can follow the maths and reasoning behind it. But since flux is a vector, shouldnt it also have a direction? I cant help but visualise all the lines of fluxing cancelling out and so the total flux vector being 0?

Comment: Flux is not a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electric flux is (the integral of) the **dot product** of electric field and area vector, hence it is a **scalar** and for a charge inside a closed surface, all these scalars will have the same sign.

For example, if you place a charge in the center of a sphere, the field lines will be in opposite direction in diametrically opposite points, but the area elements are also opposite, and their contribution to the flux will add up.